# filter by quantile at a character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have character vector from which I want to filter out the 95th quantile.

If use the following command it will change my data frame (i.e. only `n` and `name` remains).

```
  mydf %>% 
  count(name) %>%
  filter(n > quantile(n, 0.95))
```

If I use this command I get an error.

```
  mydf %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(name > quantile(name, 0.95))

  Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument 
  to binary operator.
```

Here is a small `dupt`

```
structure(list(name = c("Panda Express", "Noodles & Company", 
"Panda Express", "Panda Express", "Panda Express", "Panda Express", 
"Panda Express", "Noodles & Company", "Noodles & Company", "China"
), postal_code = c("85301", "85382", "89122", "89134", "85296", 
"85042", "89012", "15241", "85236", "85018")), .Names = c("name", 
"postal_code"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can u show the expected output>  Do you need `df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% filter(n > quantile(n, 0.95))`

Comment: @  akrun If I use this command I get "0 rows"

Comment: Please update your expected output.

Comment: @ akrun No, because I can´t get it. The Idea is to keep only the rows of my data frame in which the names that were not filtered out (because they belong to 95th quantile/they appear very often in the data frame) exists.

Comment: According to my opinion it makes no sense ordering (that's what you're doing with `quantile`) a character vector...

Comment: @  Scipione Sarlo My data frame is about restaurants. I want to filter out common food chains like "Panda Express". There is no other way in my opinion because they are not marked as such.

Comment: So, why 0.95 percentile? and not 0.99 or 0.90?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm ...you were looking for the mode of your distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `semi_join` after the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(name) %>% 
  filter(n > quantile(n, 0.95)) %>%
  semi_join(df, ., by = 'name')
```

Comment: @Banjo I am not getting error with your dput.  I use `dplyr_0.7.4`

Comment: You have to change the name of your dataframe, df is a function in R...

Comment: @  Scipione Sarlo I only called it `df` for the forum

Comment: @Banjo Your updated post is still not giving me any error. BTW, there is an extra `)` at the end of the dput